# InetAddress static method doesn't mock with PowerMockito

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

I am running into weird problem while trying to mock static methods in InetAddress. I am successfully able to mock static methods for many of other classes and all works fine, but InetAddress showing different behavior. I am using JUnit 4.x, Mockito 1.9.5 & PowerMock 1.5.6.

Given below test using Mockito and PowerMock, and InetAddress mocking works fine -

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({InetAddress.class})
public class UtilityTest {

    @Mock
    InetAddress inetAddress;

    @Test
    public void testGetCurrentHost() throws UnknownHostException {
        mockStatic(InetAddress.class);
        when(InetAddress.getLocalHost()).thenReturn(inetAddress);
        when(inetAddress.getHostAddress()).thenReturn("1.1.1.1");
        assertEquals("1.1.1.1", getCurrentHost());
    }

    private static String getCurrentHost() throws UnknownHostException {
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    }
}
```

When I put the given below method in some utility, InetAddress.getLocalHost() doesn't mock anymore and test fails.

**Move it to Utility :**

```
private static String getCurrentHost() throws UnknownHostException {
    return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
}
```

**Now my test looks like (and fails) :**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({InetAddress.class})
public class UtilityTest {

    @Mock
    InetAddress inetAddress;

    @Test
    public void testGetCurrentHost() throws UnknownHostException {
        mockStatic(InetAddress.class);
        when(InetAddress.getLocalHost()).thenReturn(inetAddress);
        when(inetAddress.getHostAddress()).thenReturn("1.1.1.1");
        assertEquals("1.1.1.1", Utility.getCurrentHost());
    }
}
```

Given below is my stacktrace -

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :1.1.1.1
Actual   :192.111.111.121
 <Click to see difference>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at com.somecompany.helper.INetTest.testGetCurrentHost(INetTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:88)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:96)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: so once you have put your method in some utility class you are no longer using your mocked object, in your case InetAddress inetAddress; will not be used by your utility class. and this is not a unit test anymore

Comment: Ankit, I put the code in this way to make it look simple. Actually I am writing a Unit test for class Utility. Please let me know if doesn't make sense. Also, I have mocked the static methods same way where static methods being called/used being used by my Utility class and it's mocked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this post is kind old, but I found a solution.

Instead doing `@PrepareForTest({ InetAddress.class })`, you must do `@PrepareForTest({ YouClassThatWrap.class })`.

In here (https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockSystem) it shows how to mock a SystemClass.

The code `@PrepareForTest({ InetAddress.class })` will not work because Powermock cannot change a System class code, so you need to mock the "wrapper" class.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
change `@PrepareForTest({InetAddress.class})` to `@PrepareForTest({Utility .class, InetAddress.class})`